# How to dynamically increase the height of a list and scroll after reaching a max height?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hi i'm trying to create a list view to which i dynamically add items in the app. I want the height of the list to grow till it reaches a defined max height, and then show a scrollbar when it overflows.

```
_buildPage() {
  return Container(
    width: widget.width,
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxHeight: widget.maxHeight,
    ),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildTitle(),
        _buildAddBump(),
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => _buildItem(_items[index]),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

This is of course not working since a `ListView` needs a pre-defined height. But wrapping the `ListView` in an `Expanded` will take all the remaining height and the `ListView` will be at maxHeight even when the items in it don't need the height.

I've tried putting the items in a `SingleChildScrollView` with a `Column` as a child, but that doesn't seem to do anything. The widget just overflows when i add more items than the height can hold. Is there a way to give a max height constraint to a list and tell it to take the height of its contents till it reaches the max height?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to add `shrinkWrap: true` to the `ListView`, but it's still not working. The page renders without errors and the `ListView` height increases as items are added, but when the height goes beyond `maxHeight`, it just overflows instead of adding a scroll.

Comment: I don't completely understand what layout do you need. Any chance `shrinkWrap: true` of ListView will work for you?

Comment: Just looked up `shrinkWrap` and it sounds like exactly what i want, so i tried it. It doesn't seem to work though. The height of the list does expand as i add items to it, but it just overflows when it reaches max height. I don't know if it's because i have the `ListView` inside a `Column`. I'll update the question that i tried `shrinkWrap`. Thanks!

Comment: Have you already tried to put the ListView inside a Container with the height parameter set to the maximum height you want to reach?

Comment: Setting a wrapping `Container`s height to maxHeight would make the `Container` take up too much vertical space right? I want the height of the entire `Column` (of which `ListView` is an item) to expand based on the content. Instead, i tried to wrap the `ListView` with a container `constraints` set to a max height, and that works. But the max height of my `ListView` depends on the height of `_buildTitle()` and `_buildAddBump()`, and `_buildAddBump()` is a multiline `TextField` so i can't give the `ListView` a `maxHeight` ahead of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like I found the solution and it's quite easy. Wrap your *ListView* inside *Flexible* and set shrinkWrap to true:

```dart
...
Flexible(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: _items.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => _buildItem(_items[index]),
    shrinkWrap: true,
  )
),
...
```

If it's not the solution, let me know what is wrong in comments.